# how to troubleshhot slow queries using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have set up a node/mongoose API project for the first time. I am having trouble trying to figure out why some of the queries are taking so long. I am trying to use, explain method but I cannot figure out where to put it.

```
    mongoose.connect(mongo.uri, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then(() => console.log('Connected'))
  .catch(error => console.log('Error' + error))
mongoose.Promise = Promise

    Object.keys(mongo.options).forEach((key) => {
  mongoose.set(key, mongo.options[key])
})

mongoose.Promise = Promise
/* istanbul ignore next */
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.prototype.view = function () {
  return { id: this.toString() }
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err)
  process.exit(-1)
})

export default mongoose



  export const create = ({ body }, res) => {
  const action = (error, collection) => {
    if (error) failure(res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', error: error }))
    else {
      collection.find({'Series.ExcludeFromAudit': false}).toArray((error, data) => {
        error && failure(res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', error: error }))
        !error && success(res.status(200).json({ data }))
      })
    }
  }

  mongoose.connection.db.collection('MetrostudyProjects', action)
}
```

Comment: so you just want to know how to use explain?, add at the end end of your query like this: `collection.find({}).explain();`

Comment: sorry for the late resposnse. i have tried that. TypeError: collection.find(...).explain(...).toArray is not a function

Comment: Don't add toArray(), explain returns an object which you can look at, just write it exactly like i did.